# Java data adjustment SQLITE with object list

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Currently, I am working on my first application using a database.
Now I am a bit confused. The application is a native Android app. I'm using SQLite as DB system.

I have some trouble to work with the data. 
At the moment I have a class Person with a few attributes (`firstname`, `lastname`, ...). But it also contains a `ID`. My `DatabaseHandler` has a method called `addPerson(Person p1)`. In the method, the `person` will be written to the DB.

The workflow I am using:
My application consists of 2 pages. The first page displays a list of all persons. The second page is to create persons with a few input fields:

[image]

After clicking the `create`-Button I create a new `object of the type Person`. If the person was successfully created I call the method  `addPerson(Person p1)`. After the person is added to the DB I get the `ID` of the `Person` - from the DB - and add it to the `Person object`. If everything worked correctly the page will be closed and I come to the start page with the list of all created `Person's`.

When changing the the first page, firstly I clear the `ArrayList<Person> persons` and read all `Person's` from the DB and add it to the `ArrayList`: `persons = DBHandler.getAllPersons();`. After getting all `Person's` I notify the `adapater` that the data has been changed.

---

This process feels very stupid. Is that the correct way I have to go? 
Or should I stop working with the class `Person` and work only with the `DBHandler`? I was searching on google but didn't find anything useful what helps me out.

Comment: Well, when do you ever really need a `Person` object? Sounds like you only need it to display entries in a Listview (you can use a CursorAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter) or to insert data into database (you can use a method with each field as a parameter instead of the object)

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the comment. Excactly. That's my question. When do I need the `Person` object. The `Person` object contains a `Date` field. So the object contains also some useful methods like `getDateAsString();` But I think it would be better to outsource methods like this. Currently the object isn't necessary (in my opinion). It makes everything  just harder. But maybe there exists some positive effects that makes it worths to go this way.

Comment: @cricket_007 what's about the legibility? I have 4 classes that need to be stored in the DB. The `DatabaseHandler` will be really large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way could be considered correct, more correct or less correct; depending very much upon opinion.

However, do you need a **Person** object? No there isn't a need but rather to some a preference. You can certainly manage the data without a **Person** object but rather use the **Cursor** object which in your case could be considered a **Person** object just with another name.

Although I've never gone down the path, you could perhaps have a sort of combination/middle option by perhaps extending the Cursor class to be a PersonCursor class so combining both.

With regard to **`ListView` adapters**, I've personally found **`CursorAdapters`** to be more suited. In short they cater for displaying multiple columns with little need for customisation. That is they allow you to provide a list of the Columns (from which the data is obtained) along with a list of the respective views (where they data is placed). Whilst, although I may be wrong, but I think ArrayAdapters, without customisation, only cater for a single element.

For example to present an identifiable person to the user you would need forename and surname. Fine for a CursorAdpater; two columns with the supplied/out of the box **`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`** would cope as you can specify to get the data from the Forename as well as get the data from the Surname and place into **`android.R.id.text1`** and **`android.R.id.text2`** respectively.

e.g.

```
    mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, //<<<< layout
            dbhlpr.getAllPeople(), //<<<< Cursor (grabbed directly)
            new String[]{
                    DBHelperPeople.FORENAME_COL, //<<<< Column(a) to show
                    DBHelperPeople.SURNAME_COL}, //<<<< Column(b) to show
            new int[]{
                    android.R.id.text1,  //<<<< view for (a)
                    android.R.id.text2}, //<<<< view for (b)
            0
    );
    mLV1.setAdapter(mSCA);
```

For the **`ArrayAdapter`** you can't, without customisation (as I understand (perhaps misunderstand)), specify two data items, so you have to combine the Forename and Surname. So you need some means of combining the two, perhaps/likely a `toString` method, specific to the **Person** class.

e.g.

```
    //  ArrayAdapter with Person[] as source
    //      built within DBHelperPeople getAllPeopleAsPersonArray
    mPeople = dbhlpr.getAllPeopleAsPersonArray();
    mAAPeeople = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            mPeople
    );
    mLV3.setAdapter(mAAPeeople);
```

However, something like the following is also required :-

```
public Person[] getAllPeopleAsPersonArray() {
    Cursor csr = getAllPeople();
    Person[] people = new Person[csr.getCount()];
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        people[csr.getPosition()] = new Person(
                csr.getLong(
                        csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelperPeople.ID_COL)
                ),
                csr.getString(
                        csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelperPeople.FORENAME_COL)
                ),
                csr.getString(
                        csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelperPeople.SURNAME_COL)
                )
                );
    }
    csr.close();
    return people;
}
```

along with a person `toString` method such as :-

```
public String toString() {
    return mForeName + ", " + mSurname;
}
```

You could argue that that the Cursor only methodology additionally requires :-

```
public Cursor getAllPeople() {
    return mDB.query(PEOPLE_TBL,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

However, it's probably a very commonly used DBHelper method (*ooops so common `getAllPeopleAsPersonArray` used it*).

Of course then a counter argument is that to have a Person object you need the constructor(s) perhaps also the getters and setters.

If you then decide to use the **ListView** rather than just look at it, say to click an item and update or delete a person. The the `CursorAdapter` can be easy to handle as the Item Listeners (`onItemClickListener` and `onItemLongClickListener`) are passed the value of the **_id** column (note that as such the Cursor used MUST have an **_id** column, a good reason to have **`_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`** or `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` (the former is more efficient for most cases)).

Although the ArrayAdapter, likewise passes id it is actually the position. Which very likely DOES NOT correlate to the ID as, SQLite id's start with 1, position's start at 0. You may delete a row that id will remain unused, until the id hits 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (*PS I'm not going to wait until the population hits that number*). So position can be quite distant from id.

However, you can (if you do it the right way, often on SO you see where the right way is not used) get the ID from the person object via the position.

e.g.

```
    id = mPeople[position].getID(); //
```

as opposed to, well nothing as id is the correct value as passed for a CursorAdapter.

---

> If the person was successfully created I call the method
>   addPerson(Person p1). After the person is added to the DB I get the ID
>   of the Person - from the DB - and add it to the Person object.

Is that Wise? Person Objects do not persist only the data in the database persists. Rather than create a new person object, adding the data to the database, then updating the person object for subsequent use. Why not just get all Persons when you need them? aka create the Persons (as a Person array) based upon the data perhaps with a `getAllPeopleAsPersonArray` method of the DBHelper(DatabaseHanlder) (*oops I think I've given away my allegiance*).

> I have 4 classes that need to be stored in the DB. The DatabaseHandler
>   will be really large.

If you have concerns extending the number of classes/tables bogging down you DBHelper. You can always split the them up, perhaps according to table. For a Shopping List App that has 7 tables/classes (Shops, Aisles, Products, ProductUsage, Rules, ShoppingList and Appvalues) I have 14 classes; a Constants class and methods class for each. The DBhelper(DatabaseHandler) pulling in from the tables classes.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Your answer helped me alot. I took the combination of both.